# Why would a locally stored video play in the Android Gallery app but show as green and only play audio in another app?

Tags: android, video

I'm trying to play a locally stored video on a tablet inside my application. The video can be opened and played normally in the default android gallery application (com.android.gallery3d) but when my app attempts to play the same video it shows up as green and only plays the audio.

Via ffmpeg I've confirmed that the video is android compatible.
Video: h264
Audio: AAC
Resolution: 1920 x 1080

Is there anything else I should be checking to make sure the video should play in my app?

Comment: "in the default android video player application" -- there is no single "default android video player application". There are thousands of Android device models, shipping with dozens, if not hundreds, of different "default android video player applications".

Comment: My bad on the "default android video player" I should have said default android gallery app "com.android.gallery3d"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested on any other device then the tablet you mentioned? Could be in incompatibility with that specific device and its drivers.

Comment: I guess I should mention that I did all that I mentioned in my question on the same device. i.e. the video plays fine on the device using the default video player application.

Comment: Right, which widget are you using to play the video in your app? MediaPlayer? VideoPlayer? ExoPlayer? I develop applications involving video playback professionally and in my experience the best option for video playback is ExoPlayer. It is more difficult to set up intially but worth it if you are going to release this app in the wild. In my experience MediaPlayer and VideoView have device specific limits and issues. I have seen that green screen you mention on some Samsung phones when using MediaPlayer before I went to ExoPlayer.

Comment: Whatever "widget" is associated with a VideoView. Not explicitly defining a MediaPlayer.

Comment: Actually, after looking at the source a little more closely, it is a MediaPlayer using a TextureView to play the video on and not a VideoView at all.

Comment: Right, unfortunately MediaPlayer is what was originally giving me fits. It seemed everytime I would solve one problem another issue would surface with it. Especially on certain devices. I know this doesnt really answer your question but I believe using the ExoPlayer library would resolve the issues you are having with MediaPlayer. I believe the samples all use a SurfaceView but you can modify it to work with a TextureView if you need too. (this is how I am using it.)